# Combining 3x IMPORTRANGE with dynamic range

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, importrange

I have 3 Google Sheet and want to combine all of them with:

- Sheet 1: 480 rows
- Sheet 2: 40 rows
- Sheet 3: 20 rows

The sheet keeps expanding by the day since the sheet's data comes from a Google Form

Currently I have the formula:

```
={IMPORTRANGE("Sheet 1 Link","Response!A2:M480");
  IMPORTRANGE("Sheet 2 Link","Response!A2:M40");
  IMPORTRANGE("Sheet 3 Link","Response!A2:M20")}
```

And I need to update the range of each sheet whenever there's new rows of data I need to manually update it into:

```
={IMPORTRANGE("Sheet 1 Link","Response!A2:M481");
  IMPORTRANGE("Sheet 2 Link","Response!A2:M42");
  IMPORTRANGE("Sheet 3 Link","Response!A2:M23")}
```

Is there any way to make the IMPORTRANGE's range dynamic depending on **Response** sheet's current row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
={QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1UWQU7d6SEHvrhvG8SAXqZZsx4L8nqfkmxhOsUGT3cmI","Sheet1!A1:C"),
                    "select Col1,Col2,Col3 where Col1 is not NULL", 0);
  QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1UWQU7d6SEHvrhvG8SAXqZZsx4L8nqfkmxhOsUGT3cmI","Sheet1!D1:F"),
                    "select Col1,Col2,Col3 where Col1 is not NULL", 0);
  QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1UWQU7d6SEHvrhvG8SAXqZZsx4L8nqfkmxhOsUGT3cmI","Sheet1!G1:I"),
                    "select Col1,Col2,Col3 where Col1 is not NULL", 0)}
```

[image: 4]